# how to create a '.htaccess' file using ssh 

Tags: python, django, ssh

i use windows xp , so i cant create a `'.htaccess'` file, and then update it to django hosting .

so i have to create it using ssh  , i use `SecureCRT 6.5`:

[image]

i know `cd` , `dir` , `mkdir` , but i dont know how to create a file , and write some word in it ?

thanks

**updated**

this is the photo i use `nano` on windows xp :

[image]

what should i do next  ?

Comment: The suggestion is to use nano while logged into the server via ssh. Don't use it in XP itself. The top line when you log in says that the server supports emacs, vim, or nano, which are common Unix editors. Nano is probably easiest to use for something simple. So 1) log in to the server. 2) Navigate to the directory you want. 3) Type "nano .htaccess". 4) Start typing the contents of your file. 5) Save the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `nano`, it's a basic text editor present on most *nix systems.

Comment: I would not say "most". But based on the MOTD in the screenshot, it is available on this particular system.

Answer (score 1):

Use [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/), [vim](http://www.vim.org/), or [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

Comment: Don't ever recommend `vim` before telling people the secret of `:q` first :)

Comment: Can i create a '.htaccess' file using nano on windows xp  ?

Comment: You don't have to use nano on the Windows machine; something like Geany would work fine.

Comment: @zjm1126: You use those on the *remote* machine. Locally you can use almost anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit on the server (if SecureCRT provides for this, I'm not sure).  Through Putty, which I do know, you can edit the file locally then upload using `scp`

```
scp ./.htaccess username@example.com:/var/www/yoursite/
```

Comment: Last time I tried, I think Explorer freaked out about filenames starting with a dot by default.

Comment: BTW- which Windows versions are affected by that? No probs on Win 7 (even though I've heard of this issue before).